# Running Selenium WebDriver test script using Selenium Grid, core java, testNG

Tags: selenium, testng

I want to run my test cases in different machines at same time (i.e cross browser testing),
 how to achieve it without using @dataProvider testNG annotation  because in my current project I am using @dataProvider to send data to my testcases?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to run your TestNG tests with the XML configuration file that TestNG supports. In the XML file, you can specify test parameter values on your test suite specification. You can replicate the XML fragment that specifies the test suite for each combination of parameter values you want to test.  Then, make those parameters arguments to your test class constructor, and make the constructor save them to instance variables.

This gets rid of the need to use a data provider, but it's an ugly solution for several reasons:

- you want to test for multiple combinations of values for your test parameters; for this you'll need to repeat the XML fragment that specifies your test suite or test class for each combination of parameter values you want to test
- the standard reporting facilities won't show the parameter values used for each test
- some other facilities in the TestNG Eclipse plugin (which I use) won't work properly either

The option I have chosen instead is as follows.  I still have test parameters on my individual tests, and a data provider that generates the parameter values.  The data provider is the same for all tests.  It reads a test parameter specification file of my own design that lists, for each test parameter in my tests, the values I want to set it to, and then generates all combinations of parameter values.

(I want to reuse WebDrivers between tests, but each combination of parameter values requires its own WebDriver.  Therefore, I maintain a mapping that maps each combination of values to a WebDriver; the first time I invoke a test with a particular combination of values, I create the corresponding WebDriver and add it to the mapping; all subsequent times, I reuse the driver found in the mapping; when a test fails, I tear it down and remove it from the mapping; after all tests are finished I tear all remaining WebDrivers in the mapping down.)

This allows me to specify the test parameters and their values once and in a single place: my specification file.
There are drawbacks, too:

- it isn't very clear from reading the testing code that these test parameters and their values are common to each test and that all the data provider does is generate all combinations of their values and apply them to each test
- test dependencies go wrong: if test T depends on test S and S fails, T should not be skipped altogether but only for the same set of parameter values that S failed for

So it is probably better not to use a dataProvider for this purpose. An alternative is to write code that takes an XML configuration file and my test parameter specification file and produces an XML configuration file that contains test suites for each combination of test parameter values.  I haven't done this because I don't know how to integrate it into the testing workflow that the Eclipse TestNG plugin supports.

I'm puzzled that TestNG doesn't seem to offer a way to let me do this already. Surely many other TestNG users must have faced this problem. I really hope there is a better way than the kludge I'm using.